# Grails string replace not working?

Tags: string, grails, replace, whitespace

I have an object being passed to the controller from a view and it contained double spaces in it that I need to remove. I have gone down the standard path and used the correct functionality to try and remove these double spaces but it doesn’t work. The string did also have a space at the from and then end that I managed to remove with .trim().

Below is what I used to try and Replace all the double spaces:

```
object = params.objectValue.trim()
object.replaceAll("  ", " ")
```

This did not work and still had the spaces so I tried this:

```
newObj = ""
object = params.objectValue.trim()
newObj = object
newObj.toString().replace("  ", " ")
```

here is an example of the string text:

```
"the person drove the car on  21/12/04 at  12:00"
```

This didn’t work either, has anyone got any idea as i dont really understand what i can do to remove these double spaces?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

`replaceAll()` doesn't mutate the original string, it returns a new string with the replaced elements. You need to reassign `params.objectValue` to the result of `replaceAll()`

```
params.objectValue = params.objectValue.replaceAll("  ", " ").trim()
```